# How to get the "Date" of Max/Min Score with (name, course) group using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

The datatable has 4 column

```
Name  Course    Date    Score
Alex  Math      10/15   90
Bob   Chem      10/28   91
Alex  Math      10/29   91
Alex  Math      12/08   89
Bob   Chem      11/23   97
Alex  Chem      10/16   94
Alex  Chem      10/30   92
Bob   Chem      10/01   94
```

I can get all max scores, min scores, and ave scores of each corresponding (name, course) group, but how can I get and output the "Max_Date" and "Min_Date" items of corresponding max/min scores? such as

```
Name  Course    Max_Date    Max    Min_Date   Min   Average
Alex  Math      10/29       91     12/08      89    90
Alex  Chem      10/16       94     10/30      92    93
Bob   Chem      11/23       97     10/28      91    94
```

Here's my Code below, how can I fetch the date items?

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => new
           {
               name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
               course = r.Field<string>("Course")
           })
           .Select(g => new
           {
               name = g.Key.name,
               course = g.Key.course,
               max = g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("score")),
               min = g.Min(r => r.Field<int>("score")),
               ave = g.Average(r => r.Field<int>("score"))
           }).Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var item in result)
Console.WriteLine(s.name + "\t" + s.course + "\t" + s.max + "\t" + s.min + "\t" + (int)s.ave);
```

Comment: same way you are doing it for score. Just convert the date in a proper date format before you apply `Max/Min/Average` on it.

Comment: @singsuyash That would get the max date, not the date of the max score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => new
           {
               name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
               course = r.Field<string>("Course")
           })
           .Select(g => new
           {
               name = g.Key.name,
               course = g.Key.course,
               max = g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("score")),
Max_Date    = g.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Field<int>("score")==g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("score")).Date    ,
Min_Date= g.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Field<int>("score")==g.Min(r => r.Field<int>("score")).Date    ,
               min = g.Min(r => r.Field<int>("score")),
               ave = g.Average(r => r.Field<int>("score"))
           }).Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var item in result)
Console.WriteLine(s.name + "\t" + s.course + "\t" + s.max + "\t" + s.min + "\t" + (int)s.ave);
```

Comment: Instead of .Date, using .Field<string>("Date"), thats correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => new
{
   name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
   course = r.Field<string>("Course")
})
.Select(g => new {
    Group = g,
    MaxEntry = g.First(gg => gg.Field<int>("score") == g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("score")))
})
.Select(g => new
{
   name = g.Group.Key.name,
   course = g.Group.Key.course,
   max = g.MaxEntry.Field<int>("score"),
   maxdate = g.MaxEntry.Field<datetime>("date"),
   min = g.Group.Min(r => r.Field<int>("score")),
   ave = g.Group.Average(r => r.Field<int>("score"))
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note: untested, but should give you an idea